# How can i optimize this mysql query in social table structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**Scheme**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `insert_at` (`insert_at`),
  KEY `fk_entity` (`entity_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entity` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entity_comment` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `fk_entity` (`entity_uid`),
  KEY `fk_user` (`user_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entity_like` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `fk_entity` (`entity_uid`),
  KEY `fk_user` (`user_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entity_share` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `share_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `fk_entity` (`entity_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entity_view` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `fk_entity` (`entity_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Query 1** - using `Left Join` [Query took 16.3032 sec]

```
SELECT c . * , COUNT(DISTINCT ev.uid) AS view_count, COUNT( DISTINCT el.uid ) AS like_count, COUNT( DISTINCT ec.uid ) AS reply_count, COUNT( DISTINCT es.uid ) AS share_count
FROM content AS c
LEFT JOIN entity_view AS ev ON ev.entity_uid = c.entity_uid
LEFT JOIN entity_like AS el ON el.entity_uid = c.entity_uid
LEFT JOIN entity_share AS es ON es.entity_uid = c.entity_uid
LEFT JOIN entity_comment AS ec ON ec.entity_uid = c.entity_uid
GROUP BY c.uid
```

**EDIT - Explain**

[image]

**Query 2** - using `Sub query` [Query took 0.0069 sec]

```
SELECT c.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity_view WHERE entity_uid = c.entity_uid) AS view_count ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity_like WHERE entity_uid = c.entity_uid) AS like_count ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity_comment WHERE entity_uid = c.entity_uid) AS reply_count ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entity_share WHERE entity_uid = c.entity_uid) AS share_count
FROM content AS c
```

**EDIT - Explain**

[image]

**Result**

```
uid | data of content | view_count | like_count | reply_count | share_count |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | .....           | 100        | 10         | 5           | 6           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | .....           | 200        | 20         | 20          | 3           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   | .....           | 300        | 10         | 10          | 2           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Explain**

- Storage Engine : `InnoDB`
- entity_{action} : Insert occurs when user {action} occurs.
  (e.g) `entity_view` is insertion occurs when user sees the content.

**Question**

> How can I optimize more in the above mysql query?

I run the query in two ways and got the results above.
This proved that `subquery` is much better.

Is there a way to a get better performance than `subquery` like this table structure? And why is `left join` so bad?

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Adding an EXPLAIN in the front of your queries will get you info about the query execution plan and help identify performance bottlenecks ( as performance depends of the table size too)

First thing i would do would be to add indexes on the columns you are doing the join (the entity_uid column on all those tables)

Comment: @NevilleK I added EXPLAIN.

Comment: @danig I added EXPLAIN.

Comment: When you are using LEFT JOIN you are inflating the number of rows.  Those are added into a temporary table and then deflated due to the group by clause. 

you can check the size of the temp table by querying `SELECT count(1) FROM content AS c LEFT JOIN entity_view AS ev ON ev.entity_uid = c.entity_uid LEFT JOIN entity_like AS el ON el.entity_uid = c.entity_uid LEFT JOIN entity_share AS es ON es.entity_uid = c.entity_uid LEFT JOIN entity_comment AS ec ON ec.entity_uid = c.entity_uid ;`

The inflate/deflate process is expensive. Your subqueries approach is the way to go imo.

Comment: 7ms is not bad.  Can a user "like" an item more than once?  If not, get rid of that one `DISTINCT` and make a `UNIQUE` index to enforce it.

Comment: Thank for answers. In this situation, I could understand find out that `LEFT JOIN` is inadequate. But, I do not know if it is the best way to use `subquery`... I need to explain of this.

Comment: @RickJames `entity_like` is just once. but other actions(share, view) is allow duplication.

Comment: Is Query 2 correct?  Shouldn't it be `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid)...`, etc?  What is the timing after that fix?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, Query 2 is correct. I think `DISTINCT` is not needed. This query shows the correct result.